# Using jquery .find() to count elements, but ignoring those elements within a particular div

Tags: jquery, html, find

I'd like to find a way to count specific child elements, but ignore any that sit within an element with a specific class.

I'm counting elements using `$('.search-me').find('[class*=seI\\-]').length` within a div element. This counts all elements that have a class beginning with `'seI-'`.

I would like to refine this to ignore any matching elements that sit within a child div element, with class `'.not-me'`.

So given this HTML:

```
<div class="search-me">
  <div class="seI-1"></div>
  <div class="seI-2"></div>
  <div class="not-me">
    <div class="seI-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

would only count seI-1 and seI-2, ignoring any elements within the .not-me class

Comment: Maybe it's better to set an additional class to make this selection easier?

Comment: These div elements are movable/sortable, so there is even less control perhaps than in the example given. The use of filter() helps enormously, as contained in two of the answers below. Thanks for your feedback, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using the [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function)'s callBack function,

```
$(".search-me").find("[class*=seI\-]").filter(function(){
 return !$(this).parent(".not-me").length
}).length
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h0gzmqnc/)

Comment: Thanks Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy, just what I needed, especially the with the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** with **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** selector

```js
var $ele = $('.search-me').find('[class*=seI\-]').filter(':not(.not-me *)');

console.log($ele.length);
$ele.css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-me">
  <div class="seI-1">1</div>
  <div class="seI-2">2</div>
  <div class="not-me">
    <div class="seI-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution - which works. The only reason I have chosen another answer is because of the use of the callback function, which provided even greater refinement.

Comment: @user1967224 : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
    document.write("Number of selected elements:" + $('.search-me').parent().find(".search-me > [class*=seI\-]").length);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="search-me">
      <div class="seI-1">1</div>
      <div class="seI-2">2</div>
      <div class="not-me">
        <div class="seI-3">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

or apply the last selector to parent object.